# Meaning of a tricky sentence

Tags: meaning

The passage below comes from Report From The Interior by Paul Auster.

In fact, it's from an article written by F. W. Dupee, a highly respected English professor in the College, five months after the Columbia revolt.

**So little unchallenged authority survives anywhere at present, even in the Vatican, that those who think they have authority tend to get ‘hung up’ on it. Many of my fellow teachers shared the Administration’s ‘hang up.’**

In this passage I'd like to know the meaning of the first sentence.
Here are my thoughts but they are two conflicting ones.

One thought,
There is none anywhere at present, even in the Vatican, that doesn't get their authority challenged, **and to address this challenge the authority have to get tough on those who challenge authority**.

The other thought which conflicts with the former.
There is none anywhere at present, even in the Vatican, that doesn't get their authority challenged, **but that's the current of the new age so the authority has no other way but to accept the change**.

Which one is right? 
If any one of the two doesn't make sense could you give me the right and precise interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, neither of your thoughts is precisely true. From the OED, the adjective 'hung up' means

> Confused, bewildered, mixed-up. Also hung-up on, obsessed with, preoccupied with. *slang*.

So authroities are obsessed with their own authority because of the constant challenges. Getting tough or accepting the challenges might be alternative outcomes but neither is indicated in the passage.

Answer (score 0):

I read it as *those who think they do have unchallenged authority tend to get ‘hung up’ on it.* Meaning they think that their august position makes them very special indeed, and that is their hangup. As mentioned by others, excessively protecting their *unchallanegeability* would be a good guess at how such a hangup might be manifest.

Comment: I would disagree. It is because so little authority goes unchallenged (ie, most authority is challenged) that those who think they have it get hung up about it. Presumably because they assume that their authority, which may only exist in their heads, will almost certainly be challenged.

Comment: I can't figure out where the disagreement lies. Your comment reads the same as my answer does. Perhaps it has to do with the idea of being able to put down challenges easily and punish or make examples of those who try.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't clear enough. Where I wrote 'those who think they have it get hung up about it', the 'it' refers to authority rather than unchallenged authority. Your answer talks about those who have unchallenged authority whereas the original quote is about those who have authority getting hung up about challenges to that authority. If anyone had unchallenged authority (is there anyone like that left?), they're unlikely to get hung up about being unchallenged.